# Can you end one sentence with a word like 'biodiversity' and start the next sentence with the very same word, 'biodiversity'?

Tags: sentence-starts, repetition

Is it possible to end a sentence with some word and then begin the next sentence with the same  word?

For example,

> The health of the environment is measured by its biodiversity. Biodiversity is ..

The repetition of the word in question, e.g. *biodiversity*: is it grammatically possible? Is there some rule against it?

Could you please provide a reference or some evidence to support your answer?

Comment: Did someone tell you it was "ungrammatical"? There is no rule against it. And, in English at least, it has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: Shakespeare; *To die, to sleep. To sleep, perchance to dream.* Does this count as evidence?

Comment: *Today I would like to talk about baseball. Baseball is...* The usage you are asking about is often used in contexts of introducing some subject, or defining some word.

Comment: It's not only possible, it can be considered good style. We like to link the first parts of new sentences back to old information and put new things at the end.

Comment: It's certainly possible.  Good writers will, in contexts where it "sounds bad", rearrange things to avoid it, but there's nothing "wrong" with it from a syntactic or semantic standpoint.

Comment: (Could you please supply a reference to support your claim to have researched this?)

Comment: This is a question about style, not grammar. It _can_ sound/look ugly, careless, clumsy, but is often unnoticeable and sometimes stylish.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. It's not only possible, it's used as a literary device for poems, speeches etc. But like any other, do not overdo it.

> "The term ***anadiplosis*** is a Greek word which means “to reduplicate”. It refers to the repetition of a word or words in successive clauses in such a way that the second clause starts with the same word which marks the end of the previous clause."

https://literarydevices.net/anadiplosis/

> Example from the movie Gladiator,
>
> “The general who became a slave. The slave who became a gladiator. The gladiator who defied an emperor. Striking story!”

Comment: There seems to be a minor inconsistency between the quoted description and the quoted example. Technically, the second sentences in that example start with "the", which isn't the last word of the previous sentences.